# Pass google plus access token got from android to server

Tags: php, android, google-api, google-plus

as title say I need to pass the access token got from mobile, wich works using the example over developer.android to my server and use that token from there to make some requests using web api. The main problem is from server side, for as much as I understood I need to attach the token passed from mobile to the current web session but i can't see how. Once I found an http request using api V1 that takes the token as paramenter and that one returns the user's information but we need to take the public posts and this part doens't work neither with the V1 nor with the V2.

I'm sorry if my question is a bit confused, but had to implement this for facebook and twitter aswell so I'm a bit exhausted right now.

TL:DR - Need to get the access token from android (done) and pass it to a web server in php (done) but once there can't use that access token in a valid way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Supplying the token as part of the call can be done either as a query parameter, or in a request header as Authorization: Bearer . Can you post the code you are using, that may make it easier to see where the problem is.

There is also no plus V2 API, so you may be looking at the wrong endpoint. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

Comment: I think the main issue is my poor knowledge of the google plus api and the fact that I'm working with others people so I don't really have a full overview of the project. At the moment I've fixed it hardcoding the token passed from the mobile in the php function. As it expects a JSON I just replaced my token in that JSON returned from his client_connect. I'll update my question with some code asap. Meanwhile thanks for your time Ian :)